# Go program does not deadlock but also never returns

Tags: go, channel

The attached gist is a simple program using channels in a producer / multi-consumer model. For some reason,

`go run channels.go` prints all the results but does not return (and does not deadlock or at least go doesn't give me that panic that a deadlock occurs.)

```
type walkietalkie struct {
    in chan int
    out chan int
    quit chan bool
}

var items []int = []int{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
}

func work1(q walkietalkie) {
    for {
        select {
        case a, more := <- q.in:
            if more {
                q.out <- a * 2
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func work2(q walkietalkie) {
    for  {
        select {
        case a, more := <- q.in:
            if more {
                q.out <- a * -1
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func work3(q walkietalkie) {
    for  {
        select {
        case a, more := <- q.in:
            if more {
                q.out <- a * 7
            }
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    results := make(chan int, 18)
    defer close(results)

    w := []walkietalkie{
        walkietalkie{ in: make(chan int, 6), out: results, quit: make(chan bool, 1) },
        walkietalkie{ in: make(chan int, 6), out: results, quit: make(chan bool, 1) },
        walkietalkie{ in: make(chan int, 6), out: results, quit: make(chan bool, 1) },
    }

    go work1(w[0])
    go work2(w[1])
    go work3(w[2])

    // Iterate over work items
    l := len(items)
    for i, e := range items {
        // Send the work item to each worker
        for _, f := range w {
            f.in <- e // send the work item
            if i == l - 1 { // This is the last input, close the channel
                close(f.in)
            }
        }
    }

    // Read all the results from the workers
    for {
        select {
        case r, more := <-results:
            if more {
                fmt.Println(r)
            } else {
                continue
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code here.  The main function spins in a tight loop after receiving all values.

Comment: The select statements make no sense. Seems you are looking for [for/range loops](https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels).

Comment: `main` runs until `results` is closed, but `results` isn't closed until `main` returns. Thus the final `for` loop in `main` will run forever. And even if it were closed correctly, the `default: break` only breaks out of the `select`, not out of the `for`, so it would still run forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems.

For 1, reading from a channel with multiple return values like

```
case a, more := <-q.in
```

Will proceed on a closed channel, with more being set to false.  In your case the `default` is never hit.

But those are in goroutines and wouldn't stop the program from exiting.  The problem is your main goroutine is doing the same thing.  Also, as it turns out, `break` will break out of selects as well as for loops.  So if you want to break the for loop then you need to use a label and [break LABEL](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Label_scopes).

As an alternative, you could also just return instead of breaking in your main goroutine.

Comment: Except that `results` isn't closed until `main` returns, making it a catch-22 as written (even if it were written to exit the loop correctly when the channel was closed).